# Application stops

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application stops when I'm switching thru any fragments (using Page Viewer ) . Basically, I can't swipe to any fragment at all without the application to stop. The error that I'm getting is " Unfortunately, TestareNou has stopped " .

Here is my MainActivity Class's code :

```
package com.example.testarenou;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {Fragment f = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
    {
    f = new DummySectionFragment();//YourFragment
    // set arguments here, if required
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    f.setArguments(args);
    break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        f = new Fragment2();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }

    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
    }


    return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }


}  public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

And here is the Log Cat : ( screenshot : http://s8.postimg.org/welool4v9/Log_Cat.jpg )

```
08-27 07:00:34.246: W/Trace(1791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-27 07:00:34.246: I/Choreographer(1791): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 07:00:34.297: D/AndroidRuntime(1791): Shutting down VM
08-27 07:00:34.297: W/dalvikvm(1791): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4cd0908)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not this many fragments: 2
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.example.testarenou.MainActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(MainActivity.java:129)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-27 07:00:34.327: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If needed to provide any aother kind of informations please let me know.

Comment: `Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` have you ever searched for this message?

Comment: Yes, I did. Most of the topics related to this subject were indicating to let it be, as it is an error that may not be effective on the actual android device. Is it something such important?

Answer (score 1):

In your `getCount()` function, you told the adapter that you have 3 pages

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
```

But when the adapter tries to get the views, you only supplied two pages, i.e. 0 and 1

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {Fragment f = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
    {
    f = new DummySectionFragment();//YourFragment
    // set arguments here, if required
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    f.setArguments(args);
    break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        f = new Fragment2();//YourFragment
        // set arguments here, if required
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);
        break;
    }

    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
    }


    return f;
    }
```

The exception is even created by yourself! So either change `getCount()` to return 2, or add `case 2:` into `getItem()`.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I've figured this out 1 hour ago. Thank you for your help kind sir. I appreciate it !